# Django + Haystack + Elasticsearch search a word with a single quote

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I have a setup of Django+Haystack+Elasticsearch. I was making a search with q="Çakıcı'nın İlk Kurşunu". And no result was appearing. As I look into the text field for this object in Elasticsearch index I see the text is stored as "Çakıcı&#39;nın İlk Kurşunu". Single quote was converted to html safe notation.

So I assume when I create index my db objects are converted by Elasticsearch.

In order to overcome this situation I have changed the q field by overwriting the clean_q method of Form class. I used the django.utils.html.escape method to escape single quote as elasticsearch stored in the index.

Here is my form code.

```
class BstBookSearchForm(SearchForm):

def no_query_found(self):
    return self.searchqueryset.all()

def search(self):
    #print self.cleaned_data.get('q')
    # First, store the SearchQuerySet received from other processing. (the main work is run internally by Haystack here).
    sqs = super(BstBookSearchForm, self).search()

    # if something goes wrong
    if not self.is_valid():
        return self.no_query_found()

    # you can then adjust the search results and ask for instance to order the results by title
    #sqs = sqs.order_by(book_name)

    return sqs         

def clean_q(self):
    return escape(self.cleaned_data['q'])
```

Is there a built in way to do this conversion, by Django, by Haystack or by Elasticsearch.

Would you consider my solution a bad practice?